# filter on related_set in Django query

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class Hardware(models.Model):
    date = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    node = models.ForeignKey('Node', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null = True)
    slot = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null = True)
    server = models.CharField(max_length=20,null = True)
    server_state = models.CharField(max_length=20,null = True)
    adapter = models.CharField(max_length=20,null = True)
    adapter_state = models.CharField(max_length=20,null = True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('date', 'node','slot')
        order_with_respect_to = 'node'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.node.name +" " + self.server

class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40, primary_key = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def inventory_by_node(request):
    day = (arrow.now().day) - 1
    nodes = Node.objects.prefetch_related("hardware_set").all()
    return render(request, 'automation/inventory_by_node.html',{'nodes':nodes})
```

I need to filter hardware_set based on date which is equal to currrent day. I tried

```
nodes = Node.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("hardwares", quesryset=Hardware.objects.filter(date=day)).all()
```

but It didn't works says no Pretch is defined

Comment: Have you read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: from django.db.models import Prefetch also would be good to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
prefetch = Prefetch("hardware_set", queryset=Hardware.objects.filter(date=day))
nodes = Node.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch).all()
```